# Java updating listmodel string

Tags: java, string, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a `JList` that uses a list model to add strings of text to the `JList`. I am having trouble figuring out how to update a selected `listModel`. I am able to select the `listModel` String (I have verified that what ever I select returns correctly) but I am unable to figure out how to update the `listModel` string I select. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Is there a `updateElement(variable)` or something I could use to accomplish this?

```
    String string1 = "hello";
    String string2 = "goodbye";
        String myItem = jlst.getSelectedValue();
    // myItem is the string returned
        listModel.addElement(string1 + string2);
// adds a new element is there anyway to update myItem so string1 and string 2 become apart of the myItem string ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using a [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html).

```
/* Create model */        
DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<>();

/* Add elements */ 
dlm.addElement("test");
dlm.addElement("test2");

/* JList to use the model */ 
JList<String> list = new JList<>(dlm);

/* Update an element */
dlm.set(1, "test3");
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am having trouble figuring out how to update a selected listmodel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). It has a working example that shows you how to dynamically add/remove elements from the `DefaultListModel` based on a user interaction with the GUI.